# How do I create a specified number of links in Knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to create a number of links (or any html element for that matter) based on a number that I have in my viewmodel. I want to do the equivalent of this in knockout js Psuedo code:

```
for(var i; i < someNo; i++){
CreateHtmlElement();
```

}

I've used the foreach binding with Knockout js before, and that lets me me create elements based on objects in an array, but I can't find anything that would do the same but for a count. Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options available to you:

-Generate an array in your view model using a computed observable qnd `foreach` on it.

Something like:

```
   this.linkCount = ko.observable(10);
   this.links = ko.computed(function() {
       return ko.utils.range(0, this.linkCount());
   }, this);
```

-Generate the array in markup like:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: ko.utils.range(0, linkCount())">
    <li>something</li>
</ul>
```

-Use the `repeat` binding created by Michael Best here: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat

Comment: Great - thanks for taking the time to explain this - will give it a go.